# How to change project tree side menu font size in JetBrains IDE

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is there any way to change the font size on the sidebar/project tree?
I have tried the default font size and theme font size and any font size I could find, but those only change the text editor or console or tab title...

[image: sidemenu]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I [googled "intellij idea project view font"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=intellij%20idea%20project%20view%20font) and came across [this post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000576110-Cannot-change-font-size-of-the-project-window) that provided [this answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000576110-Cannot-change-font-size-of-the-project-window) which worked for me.

**Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Use custom font**

[image: Font]

Comment: I did exactly the same. Then I realize it requires a restart as when I close a project and restart the IDE, the font on the side menu changed.. Thank you for your answer!